# A better Eclipse browser?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Does anybody know of a free web browser plugin for eclipse that is better than the built-in browser? I searched but couldn't find anything. I know Tasktop has one, but it's not free...

Answer (score 0):

It was (in 2010):
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-advanced-browser

now is integrated with http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/j-office-java-fx-office#.U0-y8HB5B74  (http://www.joffice.eu)

Now you can only do something like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056165/2288169